# Find the mathematical expectation and the dispersion of the number of hits on target

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I have the following task:

Two guns independently of each other make 5 shots on target. The probability of hitting the target with any projectile for the first gun is 0.2, for the second - 0.7. Determine the mathematical expectation and dispersion of the number of hits on target for both guns.

I know how to calculate mathematical expectation and dispersion for discrete random variable. I have a problem with filling the table for `x` and `p`. For example, for `0` hits the probability is `power(q1, 5) * power(q2, 5)`. That's pretty easy. But it becomes much more complicated for, for example, 5 hits. It's

`power(p1, 5) * power(q2, 5) +`

`power(p1, 4) * power(q1, 1) * power(p2, 1) * power(q2, 4) +`

`power(p1, 3) * power(q1, 2) * power(p2, 2) * power(q2, 3) +`

`power(p1, 2) * power(q1, 3) * power(p2, 3) * power(q2, 2) +`

`power(p1, 1) * power(q1, 4) * power(p2, 4) * power(q2, 1) +`

`power(q1, 5) * power(p2, 5)`.

And I was wandering, am I doing it correctly? Maybe there is an easier way?

Thanks in advance for any help!

P.S. Sorry for my formatting. It's my first question so far:)

Comment: For any fixed gun, you just have a standard binomial distribution.  Thus the probability that gun $i$ has exactly $k$ hits is $\binom 5k\,p_i^kq_i^{5-k}$.

Comment: @lulu isn't it gonna be the same? I mean, for 5 hits it's still gonna be pretty long, because I will have to use this formula 6 times

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  To get $n$ total hits you need to consider all combinations of $(k_1,k_2) $ with $k_1+k_2=n$.  Happily $10$ is a pretty small number so it's not difficult to enumerate all the cases.

Comment: Note: if all you want is the expectation and variance, that should be easier.  Linearity gets you the expected number of hits at once.  Variance can be done in a similar way (though it is a bit messier).

Comment: @lulu not sure if I know what linearity is. Could you please point out where I can read about it?

Comment: [Linearity of Expectation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linearity-of-expectation/) is a key property of expected value, well worth reading about.  Here, for instance, the expected number of hits is just $5\times (.2+.7)$.  Variance can be done using the fact that the variance of a distribution $Z$ is $E[Z^2]-E[Z]^2$.

Comment: @lulu Wow! That's pretty cool! I didn't know about it. Thank you so much! If you write it as an answer I will totally mark it as a correct one

Comment: How about this:  you post your computation below when you are done and I'll check it for you.  Be careful, variance is definitely more work here.

Comment: @lulu sorry for late answer, didn't see your last comment. I actually got stuck with $$E[Z^2]$$. I found it for each of the guns separately (and got 1.8 and 13.3) but I cannot combine them. If I just add them, my variance will be negative. What should I do? If I multiply them, I get $$E[Z] = 4.5$$ and $$D[Z] = 3.69$$. But I doubt that it's the right answer

Comment: @lulu I also found this formula: $D[XY] = M[X^2]M[Y^2] — M[X]^2M[Y]^2$. I got `11.69` using it